# How to move a post from one category to another

Tags: php, functions, categories

I am new to PHP. Please help me to achieve the below scenario. I am trying to achieve this from the last 3 days.

I've two categories in my WordPress dashboard named "Available (id:3)" and "Booked (id:4)".
In the "available" category a few posts are there.

When I submit a "contact form 7" successfully, I would like to move that post to the "booked" category.

I tried something like below in my functions.php

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', function ($cf7) {
    function wp_set_post_categories( $post_ID = 0, $post_categories = array(), $append = true ) {
    $post_ID     = (int) $post_ID;
    $post_type   = get_post_type( $post_ID );
    $post_status = get_post_status( $post_ID );
    // If $post_categories isn't already an array, make it one:
    $post_categories = (array) $post_categories;
    if ( empty( $post_categories ) ) {
        if ( 'post' == $post_type && 'auto-draft' != $post_status ) {
            $post_categories = array( get_option( 'default_category' ) );
            $append          = false;
        } else {
            $post_categories = array(4);
        }
    } elseif ( 1 == count( $post_categories ) && '' == reset( $post_categories ) ) {
        return true;
    }
 
    return wp_set_post_terms( $post_ID, $post_categories, 'category', $append );
}
});
```

Whatever I am writing inside the action its not even executing

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', function ($cf7) {
    // not working anything, only print_r command working
});
```

All help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', function ($cf7) {
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $data = $submission->get_posted_data();

    if( empty($data['_wpcf7_container_post']) )
        return;

    $post_id = (int) $data['_wpcf7_container_post'];

    wp_remove_object_terms( $post_id, 'available', 'category');
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'booked', 'category');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But it's not working. I pasted this code to my functions.php. Do I need to include anything else? Still, the contact form is submitting but after contact form submission the code you have given me not even executing or throwing any error. That is the issue.

Comment: @sajeergraphix try to replace `available` with 3 and `booked` with 4 (without quotes)

Comment: No brother. No Luck. see the link please. it's still showing the category under available.
http://uei.iwu.mybluehost.me/free212/test/